# Fully Qualified Xpath returns null

Tags: xpath

```
<Trial1Response xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/Sql/2008/05/Procedures/dbo">
<Trial1Result>
<DataSet xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Data">
    <xs:schema id="NewDataSet" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata">
    <xs:element msdata:IsDataSet="true" name="NewDataSet">
    <xs:complexType>
    <xs:sequence>
    <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" name="NewTable">
    <xs:complexType>
    <xs:sequence>
    <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="cust_id" type="xs:int">
    </xs:element>
    <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="fname" type="xs:string">
    </xs:element>
    <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="lname" type="xs:string">
    </xs:element>
    <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="addr" type="xs:string">
    </xs:element>
    <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="city" type="xs:string">
    </xs:element>
    <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="order_id" type="xs:int">
    </xs:element>
    <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="amount" type="xs:int">
    </xs:element>
    <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="particulars" type="xs:string">
    </xs:element>
    </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    </xs:schema>
<diffgr:diffgram xmlns:diffgr="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-diffgram-v1">
<NewDataSet xmlns="">
<NewTable><cust_id>1</cust_id><fname>Akshay</fname><lname>Jain</lname><addr>Borivali</addr><city>Mumbai</city><order_id>221</order_id><amount>41</amount><particulars>Item B</particulars>
</NewTable>
<NewTable><id>223</id><Akshay1id>682</Akshay1id><amount>345</amount><particulars>Item A</particulars>
</NewTable>
</NewDataSet>
</diffgr:diffgram>
</DataSet>
</Trial1Result>
<ReturnValue>0</ReturnValue>
</Trial1Response>
```

I want to extract the data between the tags NewDataSet. For this, I am using the following Xpath:

```
/*[local-name="Trial1Response" and namespace-uri()="http://schemas.microsoft.com/Sql/2008/05/Procedures/dbo"]/*[local-name="Trial1Result" and namespace-uri()="http://schemas.microsoft.com/Sql/2008/05/Procedures/dbo"]/*[local-name="DataSet" and namespace-uri()="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Data"]/*[local-name="diffgr:diffgram" and namespace-uri()="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-diffgram-v1"]/*[local-name="NewDataSet" and namespace-uri()=""]
```

I get null as my result. What am I doing wrong? 
I am expected to use the fully qualified Xpath because Logic apps do not work without it

Edit: I have edited the XML after comments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct your xml.

And change `local-name` to `local-name()`

**like this**

```
/*[local-name()="Trial1Response" and namespace-uri()="http://schemas.microsoft.com/Sql/2008/05/Procedures/dbo"]/*[local-name()="Trial1Result" and namespace-uri()="http://schemas.microsoft.com/Sql/2008/05/Procedures/dbo"]/*[local-name()="DataSet" and namespace-uri()="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Data"]/*[local-name()="diffgram" and namespace-uri()="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-diffgram-v1"]/*[local-name()="NewDataSet" and namespace-uri()=""]
```

note: no need of using namespace-uri() if you have single/unique elements in the xml.

Comment: It works on an online Xpath evaluator but not on Logic Apps. Maybe something is wrong with Logic Apps.

Comment: @user2684198 sorry no idea with logic apps.